# Custom settings and wsgi in django 1.10 give me error

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I have this bug with custom settings running the server:

```
 salahaddin@TulipanROG  ~/Proyectos/tiempoturco/tiempoturco  (tiempoturco)  ./manage.py runserver                                                                                                                                            ✓  640  23:22:06 
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 19, 2016 - 23:22:07
Django version 1.10a1, using settings 'tiempoturco.settings.dev'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f288d67f2f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 142, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 64, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/tiempoturco/tiempoturco/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 153, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 79, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I have this folder structure:
[image]

And here my wsgi code:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tiempoturco.settings.dev")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And my manage.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tiempoturco.settings.dev")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

What is wrong?
I can execute migrations and create super users, use the shell plus and other commands but i can run the server. I tried change the setting value to production and dev, putting this values in `__init__.py` and doing other thins but nothing.

And `middleware_clases`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I can't find information about this and i'm testing `django 1.10`.

I haven't problems with django `1.9.7`, i don't know why. In same way, when i create a project with `wagtail 1.6`i haven't problem in runserver, `wagtail 1.6` installs `django 1.9.7`yet, but i replace then it for `django 1.10` and then try to run the project after run migrations and create a super user, and when i go to the home in the browser i can see the page, and admin too.

So, i haven't problems with use other app, but create handly multiple settings myself give me this bug yet.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

Comment: (Or `MIDDLEWARE` setting)

Comment: Already done, and `WSGI_APPLICATION` it's the default `django 1.10` setting put.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try changing the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Yeah, problem is whit some middleware classes.

Comment: I just renamed 'MIDDLEWARE' to 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' in my settings.py and everything worked. Thanks

Comment: This works, but note that 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' is [deprecated in 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/). Unfortunately, it's up to the middleware writers to fix any given package.

Comment: Renaming to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES solved this issue for me, and I'm running 1.10.3

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39004873/3344078 below, it might be worth a try to update your Middleware classes if you have custom ones (which should be absolutely no hassle at all if you didn't do too fancy stuff) and also update third party middlewares e.g. via pip

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem with when upgrading my app to django 1.10. First I would try changing MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to MIDDLEWARE because with Django 1.10 they introduced a new style of middleware outline here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/

If that doesn't work, I would suggest checking your django middleware files, I had to change all classes that took object to MiddlewareMixin which you can import by calling:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
```

In my case I changed

```
class SiteMiddleware(object):
...
```

to

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class SiteMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
...
```

Comment: For me, I had to change MIDDLEWARE to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES because I was using middleware from django 1.9

Answer (score 2):

I tried directly in Django 1.10! Initially it showed 
"TypeError: object() takes no parameters" error.
After I changed MIDDLEWARE to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in my settings.py, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I would add that in addition to what mol mentioned, during process of upgrading Django I had to temporary disable the linked virtual host. Also try freshly upgrading to Django 1.10 (uninstall Django 1.9, then install Django 1.10).

You might need to additionally clear all Django sessions as well.